# Halachot Gedolot from Spain

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, geonim

Tosfot in Pesachim 30a paragraph Amar Rava quotes a rule from the Halachot Gedolot from Spain.

> ובה"ג של אספמיא פסק דחתיכה בחתיכות בנ"ט ומייתי מדרבא בפ' גיד הנשה

The Tosfot in Chulin 97a quotes the same BHG from Spain.
What is this book? From what is it different from the standard BHG?

It's important to note that the Tosfot quotes a lot of Geonic sources that he doesn't identify with the BHG from Spain: (from the Tosfot in Chulin):

- Seder Tanayim Veamorayim;
- BHG;
- Sheiltot Derav Achay;
- Teshuvat Hageonim, quoting RY Tov Elem (Bonfils);

Comment: Wikipedia discusses the different versions

Comment: Might it be the Rif?

Comment: Tosfot calls generally the Rif differently, may be halachot haraf Alfas, I don't remember exactly

Comment: @DoubleAA `נוסח זה נקרא על ידי חלק מהחוקרים "הלכות גדולות אספמיא", מתוך תפיסה (כנראה שגויה) שזה היה הנוסח שעמד בפני חכמי ספרד.` the words of the Wikipedia seems strange, Tosfot was wrong?

Comment: http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?p=114155&sid=ecabcf74f7fe2eacb434408c4d52c128#p114155

Answer (score 7):

According to [David Cassel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Cassel) in his book "תשובות גאונים קדמונים", [p. 4](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=IoRCAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA1&lpg=RA1-PA1&dq=%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94%22%D7%92%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%90&source=bl&ots=ncH3iYmqRJ&sig=ACfU3U0rGbUU4Q0f31-wjGrJAfE2yaZr5w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHyoya-9H3AhXGgP0HHQk2BQkQ6AF6BAgUEAM&safe=strict#v=onepage&q=%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94%22%D7%92%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%90&f=false), there were two versions of Halachot Gedolot, one from Spain and one from France. The latter one was identified with [Rabbi Yosef Tov-Elem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Samuel_Bonfils). The Spanish one, according to Cassel, is the one we have before us, since it had Hilchot Nazir, just like the one we have. However, our Halachot Gedolot also has later additions to the text, including from the Rif. Similarly, he notes, there were two versions - French and Spanish - of the book Seder Tannaim V'Amoraim, with the French one also connected to Rabbi Yosef Tov-Elem. I'll add that Solomon Schechter, several decades later, discovered that there are [two versions of Avot DeRabbi Natan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avot_of_Rabbi_Natan#The_two_existing_forms_(recensions)_of_Avot_de-Rabbi_Nathan), and the versions differentiate between Spanish/Mizrachi and French/Ashkenaz.

Comment: It's interesting. The same Tosfot quotes separately the 3: the teshuvot hageonim written by Rabbi Yosef Tov elem and the Halachot Gedolot and the Halachot Gedolot from Spain

Comment: I was sure that will send an answer and wase expected it!

Comment: This Tosfot quotes also Seder Tanayim Veanorayim separately.

Comment: Once you're exploring the topic of Spanish/French recensions, it's worth noting that there are 2 versions of the Iggereth of R. Sherira Gaon.

Comment: @Deuteronomy thanks, I forgot to put that one in.